# Need help recovering data from corrupted userdata partition (Galaxy S3 International)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, data-recovery

Phone: Galaxy S3 International i9300

The phone started bootlooping, and I tried to do a factory reset, but it seems my phone went off during the process.  I'm trying to obtain images etc. off the phone.

I could connect to the phone using adb after some help.  All the other partitions except the USERDATA (/dev/block/mmcblk0p12) mount fine.  Trying to mount this partition gives an error about a bad magic number on the superblock.  I pulled the ext4 partition with adb pull, and none of the other superblocks have a valid magic number: the lower numbers report invalid magic numbers, while for higher numbers I get:

```
e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open mmcblk0p12.img
Could this be a zero-length partition?
```

I tried regenerating the superblocks, but the subsequent e2fsck could not find the root folder so everything gets hosed that way.

I've also tried using `foremost` and `recoverjpeg`as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery , both of which recovered zero files.

However, from what I have read (can not currently find source), I understand that the virtual SD card on the Galaxy S3 is a partition on the 
USERDATA partition, so I'm not sure if it may be mountable in a loopback fashion, in which case it's possible these tools will not detect anything even if the data I'm looking for is there.

Questions:

1. What else can I try to repair/recover the file system?
2. Is my understanding about a partition within a partition correct, or am I grasping at straws?  (i.e. if `foremost`/`recoverjpeg` can't find a `.jpeg`, should I assume it is gone?)

Output of `mke2fs -n mmcblk0p12.img`

```
mke2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
mmcblk0p12.img is not a block special device.
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
1703936 inodes, 6809600 blocks
340480 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
208 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000
```

Comment: Have you checked with our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info)? Especially the last link there might prove helpful in your context: [One Way to Use a Linux Computer to Recover Files from an Android Device](http://www.df.lth.se/~jokke/androidfilerecovery/).

Comment: Don't see anything on the tag-wiki that would help me unfortunately.  Had also tried `testdisk` on the partition image already, without any luck.

Comment: Could it be that partition is encrypted? // Concerning the virtual SD: It's certainly not a "partition inside a partition", but rather a FUSE mount of a directory residing on that partition.

Comment: I got the phone from someone else, so I can't say it is not encrypted for sure -  but I am not aware of anything like that.  Does the FUSE mount basically just duplicate access to the underlying directory at a specific mount point, then?  In this case, it basically seems like I'm at a dead end...

Comment: In this case, AFAIK that's exactly what happens: to avoid "clutter" (the classical "insufficient storage" issue, where internal storage runs out of space while there's plenty on the internal SD card), both share the same partition – and the "internal SD" basically is a directory on "internal storage", presented as "separate mount point" for compatibility reasons.